# How to get the handle of a SysTreeView32's scrollbar?

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi, mfc, spy++

I have a [SysTreeView32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tree-view-control-reference) control with two associated scrollbars:

[image]

Starting from the window in which the tree is located, I am not able to recover the scrollbars' handles; I wrote a simple recursive function to navigate the control and all its children:

```
TestScroll( HWND hwnd, UINT msg, UINT_PTR nId, DWORD nTickCount)
{
    CWnd* pNextWnd = tmpWnd->GetWindow( GW_CHILD) ;

    if ( pNextWnd != NULL)
        TestScroll( pNextWnd->GetSafeHwnd(), msg, nId, nTickCount) ;

    pNextWnd = tmpWnd->GetNextWindow( GW_HWNDNEXT) ;

    if ( pNextWnd != NULL)
        TestScroll( pNextWnd->GetSafeHwnd(), msg, nId, nTickCount) ;

}
```

When I get to the SysTreeView32 control, I can't get further into the hierarchy and it seems that there are no more child controls; but Spy++ confirms that the scrollbars are indeed present.

Any advice is welcome, thank you very much!

Comment: What *problem* are you trying to solve?

Comment: Almost certainly the solution to your problem doesn't require you to poke at internal implementation details of common controls

Comment: @IInspectable The reason I'm trying to get the handles of the scrollbar is that I'm trying to subclass at rutime the scrollbars of the tree.

Comment: You are still just explaining what you believe to be the solution to your problem. But what is the *problem* you are trying to solve?

Comment: @IInspectable I'm trying to skin the tree scrollbar, changing the default colors of the scrollbar elements (thumb, arrows). In order to change the colors of the control, I created a class that intercepts the scrollbar's paint messages, and draws the control manually (doing a subclass operation). This subclass worked properly on one tree, and now I was trying to apply the same subclass to all the trees in the same window. For this reason, I was trying to create a recursive method that automatically scrolls through all the controls contained in the window and subclasses all the existing scrollb

Comment: [There are two types of scrollbars](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=39413). Your solution will only ever work with one of those. The other one is off limits.

Comment: @IInspectable I see, thanks for your time!

Comment: You may have better luck using the [Visual Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/visual-styles-overview) API to skin your application. It's fairly incomplete and poorly documented, but apparently it allows you to assign [custom colors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/themesfileformat-overview#control-panelcolors-section) to scrollbars.

Comment: The scrollbars that are part of a window's nonclient area are drawn in response to `WM_NCPAINT` and other messages, and also at times not associated with a message. You can get some of the way with sub-classing but it's very hard to do it properly as Windows simply isn't designed to let you custom draw these elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows does provide a scrollbar class that can exist as a HWND but the treeview control (and most of the other common controls) use [the other scrollbar type](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=39413) which is a part of the parent HWND (`WS_HSCROLL` and/or `WS_VSCROLL` styles).

Comment: I had found this article shortly after writing my question, but spy ++ had given me some hope as I could see that there were handles associated with the two scrollbars; thanks for the clarification!